# Wrong baseline for <input type="file"/>

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a strange problem with the `input file` HTML5 tag. [image: This is how it looks]

The text is higher than the button. It hasn't any CSS atribute. I'm using Bootstrap front-end framework, maybe that's the problem? How can I repair it?

Thank's advance!

EDIT:

This is my  form

```
<form action="/change" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">

    <span class="help-block">Username</span>
    <input id="checkuser" type="text" name="nuser" value="<%= user.user %>"/>
    <i id="usricon" style="margin-left: 8px; margin-right: 5px;" class=""></i>
    <small id="usrc" style="padding-bottom: 3px;"></small>

    <span class="help-block">Email</span>
    <input id="checkmail" type="text" name="nmail" value="<%= user.mail %>"/><i
    id="milicon" style="margin-left: 8px; margin-right: 5px;"></i>
    <small id="milc" style="padding-bottom: 3px;"></small>

    <span class="help-block">Password</span>
    <input type="password" id="opass" name="opass" placeholder="Your old password"/>
    <i id="pssicon1" style="margin-left: 8px; margin-right: 5px;" class=""></i>
    <small id="pssc1" style="padding-bottom: 3px;"></small><br>
    <input type="password" id="ps" name="npass" placeholder="Your new password"/>
    <i id="pssicon2" style="margin-left: 8px; margin-right: 5px;" class=""></i>
    <small id="pssc2" style="padding-bottom: 3px;"></small>

    <span class="help-block">Avatar</span>
    <img class="img-rounded" style="height: 80px; width 80px" 
      src="<%= user.path %><%= user.avatar %>">
    <input id="avat" type="file" name="navatar" accept="image/*">

    <span style="margin-top: 1em" class="help-block">Background</span>
    <input type="file" id="back" name="nback" accept="image/*"><br>

    <input class="button" type="submit">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can't style an input file tag.  That is all done by the browser.  There are some techniques for overlaying styles on top of it, but the default styling always remains.

Comment: But normally the input file doesn't look like that, it's really weird

Comment: Sure, here you got http://i45.tinypic.com/spu92v.png. I have some JS related with the element, but just check de value. I think is a bootstrap problem